# How to call def in python to ajax

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I want to delete 1 row data in the database. When I click on button Delete then display a dialog to confirm. But when I using ajax I can't delete. Please help me!
this is my view code

```
def company_delete(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    company = Company.objects.get(pk=int(QueryDict(request.body).get('postpk')))
    company.delete()
    response_data = {}
    response_data['mgs'] = 'Company was deleted'
    return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps(response_data),
        content_type="application/json"
    )
else:
    return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps({"nothing to see": "this isn't happening"}),
        content_type="application/json"
    )
```

This is my html code:

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                        <a id="opener" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="dialog" title="Are you sure?">
                        <p>Some helpful info here</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

This is my jquery code

```
 $(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            height: 140,
            modal: true,
            show: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 1000
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "explode",
                duration: 1000
            },
            buttons: {
                "Yes": function delete_company(companyid) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "company_delete/",
                        data: { postpk : companyid },
                        success: function (json) {
                            $('#dialog' + companyid).hide();
                            console.log("company deletion successful");
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    });
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
        $("#opener").click(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        });
    });
```

This is my urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^delete/(?P<company_id>\d+)/$', views.company_delete, name='company_delete'),]
```

Comment: @TommyOliver Try using the browser debugger's Network tab (F12) to see if your request makes it to the web server.

Comment: url(r'^delete/(?P<company_id>\d+)/$', views.company_delete, name='company_delete'),

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your URL pattern expects the call to come to "`delete/<company_id>`" but your JQuery ajax url is pointed to "company_delete" and you are doing a POST, which wouldn't send company id in URL.

Did you mean to give "company/delete" in AJAX? (which makes sense if your urls.py is part of an app and there is another top level/project level urls.py that "company" as url pattern)

And for delete it is better to use 'type': 'delete' in Jquery ajax call (and make the necessary change in Django view for this)